# Yii2 mongoDb update error

Tags: mongodb, activerecord, yii2

I have problem with my Yii2 mongoDb model. I want to update my User object.In model class i have:

```
public function attributes() {
    return [
        '_id',
        'username',
        'password',
        'email',
    ];
}
```

and i want to update my user : "www".
So i do this on that way:

```
$user = User::findOne(["username"=>"www"]);
        $user->email = "www@www.www";
        if($user->save()){
            var_dump('inserted');
        }else{
            var_dump('not inserted');
        }
```

When i dump user before create i get email which I set.

And on dump i get "not inserted". Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be you have a validation problem ..
try (just for debugging)  using save(false), so don't perform validation ..

```
$user = User::findOne(["username"=>"www"]);
    $user->email = "www@www.www";
    if($user->save(false)){
        var_dump('inserted');
    }else{
        var_dump('not inserted');
    }
```

If in this condition the $user is saved . inspect your model rule for define what rule could fail

You can obtain the error this way

```
if (!$user->validate()) {
     var_dump($user->errors)
}
```